# django rest framework comment form not working

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

i created this site using django rest framework so that it works without refreshing the page at all,

http://192.241.153.25:8000/#/post/image3

and using angular js's route function was great choice of building a single page app.

but for some reason, the comment box doesn't seem to work possibly because it is put inside the angular js's template.

it throws me csrf token missing error even though the token is included.

judging by the fact that {% csrf token %} tag is visible as a text makes me think that the angular template cannot read the django tag.

could anyone tell me why the comment form isn't functioning and how i can fix this?

```
    (function() {
  angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
.controller('FilesListCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {//this one controller is new


  angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(_post){
    $scope.styles = producePostStyle(_post)
  });
  function producePostStyle(post) {
    return { "background-image": "url(" + post.image + ")" }
  }
$scope.producePostStyle = producePostStyle;
  $http.get('/api/posts/').then(function (response) {
              $scope.viewStyle = {
                  background: 'url('+response.data.results.image+')'
              };

  });

    $scope.images = [];
    $scope.next_page = null;
    var in_progress = true;

    $scope.loadImages = function() {
    //alert(in_progress);
            if (in_progress){
            var url = '/api/posts/';//api url
            if ($scope.next_page) {
                url = $scope.next_page;
            }
            $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data.results);//according to api
                $scope.next_page = data.next;//acccording to api

                if ( ( $scope.next_page == null ) || (!$scope.next_page) ) {
                    in_progress = false;
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.loadImages();
}])
angular.module('app')
.controller('profile_image', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {//this one controller is new

  $http({
    url: '/api/users/profile/',
    method: "GET",
    params: {username: 'lifeto'}
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log("Profile Image");
    console.log(response);
    $scope.lifeto_img = response.data;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log("Error fetching profile image!");
});

}])




.directive('whenScrolled', function($document) {//another directive
        return function(scope, elm, attr) {
            var raw = elm[0];

             $document.bind('scroll', function() {
                if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                    scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
                }
            });
        };
    })
    .config(function($resourceProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
      $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
      // Don't strip trailing slashes from calculated URLs
      $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          template: '<posts></posts>'
        })
        .when('/posts', {
          template: '<posts></posts>'
        })
        .when('/post/:postId', {
          template: '<post></post>'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
  angular.module('app')
    .constant('API_URL', '/api/posts/');
  angular.module('app')
    .factory('Posts', function($resource, API_URL) {
      return $resource(API_URL, {format: 'json'}, {
        queryPosts: {
          method: 'GET',
          isArray: false
        },
        getPostInfo: {
          url: API_URL + ':postId/',
          method: 'GET',
          isArray: false,
          params: {
            postId: '@postId',
            format: 'json'
          }
        }
      });
    });
  angular.module('app')
    .directive('post', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/static/post.html',
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, $routeParams, Posts) {
          $scope.post = null;

          function clean(id) {
        return id.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-");
      }

      function _initialize() {
   Posts.getPostInfo({
     postId: clean($routeParams.postId)
   })
              .$promise
                .then(function(result) {
                  $scope.post = result;
                  console.log(result)
                });
          }
          _initialize();
        }
      };
    });
  angular.module('app')
    .directive('posts', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/static/posts.html',
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, Posts) {
          $scope.posts = [];
          function _initialize() {
            Posts.queryPosts().$promise.then(function(result) {
              $scope.posts = result.results;
            });
          }
          _initialize();
        }
      };
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you added

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

$http will take care of csrf.

Now you can post data using `$http`

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/url/',
    data: {
        "key1": 'value1',
    },
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    #do
    },
    function errorCallback(response) {
    #do
    });
```

**Note:** Dont use Ajax Post here. For that you have to do some csrf things other than this.

Comment: thank you for the answer. but i am new to angular js, and having a hard time figuring out where and how to put this thing. is this correct? it still throws me the same csrf missing error. https://dpaste.de/54na (what goes into 'data')?

Comment: paste you app.js also in dpaste.

Comment: this is the whole angular js. if you mean ajax code for the index.html i can give it to you as well. https://dpaste.de/GMGF#L2

Comment: What i answered is, change your `$('#comment_form').on` function to the code using `$http` inside a controller. https://dpaste.de/4dnj

Comment: thanks for that. but i've already tried that and it's still throwing csrf token missing or wrong error. :(

Comment: is it uploaded your code github? is it private ? so that i can go through it.

Comment: if you still want to go over it, i can invite you to my bitbucket repository. just leave me your id.

Comment: ok.my email id is latheefvkpadi@gmail.com.i will go through if